# Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following simple MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0) -- (3,3);
  \pgfmathparse{2+1}
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (3,\pgfmathresult);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I expect to have, as an output, one red line, however this is the result that I get:

[image]

So, is it a bug, feature, or simply me doing something wrong?

Comment: Doesn't the second one (in red) should hide the first one?

Comment: I don't know the details, but the value of `\pgfmathresult` changes at `\draw[red]`. Try `\pgfmathsetmacro\temp{2+1}\draw[red] (0,0) -- (3,\temp);` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Is this documented somewhere? I managed to miss it in the manual.

Comment: No problem. I searched for "pgfmathresult" in the manual, but didn't find a proper explanation.

Comment: @Jubobs: would you call it a bug? It is rather confusing...

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug but I agree that it should be documented. Perhaps you should drop the `tikz` maintainers an email, or open an issue on the dedicated page...